# String matching on a R column

Tags: r, regex, string

My data frame has a column on which I am trying to run string matching and then update the string upon match.I have tried couple approaches but none seemed to have work. My frame looks like the below. For column "IntNames" row 2, I would like to substitute "clin2|clin3|clin4" with only clin2 and for row3 "clin6|clin7|clin8|clin9|clin10" with only clin6. The idea is to only retain the first element for such values. I appreciate all your help and input on this.

```
DataFrame:    

   IntNames                   values1    values2
clin1                           100        10
clin2|clin3|clin4               200         4
clin6|clin7|clin8|clin9|clin10  240         5

This is what I have written:
newIntNames <- ifelse(myFrame$IntNames=="|",myFrame$IntNames[0],myFrame$IntNames)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do this (assuming that `IntNames` is a character vector):

```
myFrame$IntNames<- unlist(lapply(strsplit(myFrame$IntNames, "[|]"), `[[`, 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Drop the ifelse statement and use [substitution](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) for this task:

```
myFrame$IntNames <- sub('\\|.*', '', myFrame$IntNames)

#   IntNames values1 values2
# 1    clin1     100      10
# 2    clin2     200       4
# 3    clin6     240       5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `sub` and a regular expression.

```
## Replicate your data
myFrame = read.table(text="IntNames    values1 values2
clin1   100 10
clin2|clin3|clin4   200 4
clin6|clin7|clin8|clin9|clin10  240 5",
header=TRUE)

myFrame$IntNames = sub("(\\.*?)\\|.*", "\\1", myFrame$IntNames) 
myFrame
  IntNames values1 values2
1    clin1     100      10
2    clin2     200       4
3    clin6     240       5
```